# How to bind select?

Tags: reactjs

How to display selected from "Main select" to "Attached select" so that what was selected in "Main select" is automatically selected in "Attached select"?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [optionValue, setOptionValue] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

  const onHandleOption = () => {
    return optionValue.map((i, idx) => {
      return <option id={idx}>{i}</option>;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Main select</p>
      <select>{onHandleOption()}</select>

      <p>Attached select</p>
      <select>{onHandleOption()}</select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add an event onSelect in your main select and every time you select something push it in array and this array would be printed every time you change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a value to the select element:  `<select value={selectValue} />`, which will make this more of a controlled component.

So then during the onChange for the first select element, you want to set a state of the selected item and make sure it is the value for the second select element.

Ex:

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(someOption);

<select onChange={set option here} />
<select value={selectedOption} />
```

They will need to have identical `<option />` elements to make sure the value binds from one to another.

React Forms docs for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

EDIT:

Here is an example of how this could work:

```
  const options = [1, 2, 3];
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(1);

  const onHandleOption = e => {
    setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Main select</p>
      <select onChange={onHandleOption}>
        {options.map(option => {
          return <option>{option}</option>;
        })}
      </select>

      <p>Attached select</p>
      <select value={selectedOption} readOnly>
        {options.map(option => {
          return <option>{option}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
```

As shown above, the second select element has a value and readOnly declared as we do not want it to be changed by the user, a controlled component. The first select element has the onChange handler to set a shared state object to be used in the second select element. Also as I have stated they both need identical options as the value from one to another select element will need to bind. Hope this can be of help.

Comment: This does not work (
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-glade-e8042

Comment: The above code was meant as a demonstration. Of course a `<select />` element needs `<options />`, it is not a closed-off element. Check edits above for what would work for you.